@nestjs/typeorm: @Unique annotation do not respect the "name" parameter - NestJS, TypeORM and PostgreSQL
When i'm setting the @Unique like that:
@Unique('uk_process_proposal_number', ['proposalNumber'])

The constraint does wasn't created with this name on postgres.

Anyone can help?
I've tried to update the package and then removing the unique so it will be created and the problem persists

did you ran any migrations or are using synchronize:true? btw this has nothing to do with Nestjs but TypeORM
